# How to make sure validator error messages are displayed to the right?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-validators

First, take a look at the thing we can see

[image: Error messages]

As you can see, at the **From** we have an invalid email address, while at the **To** we have no email address. Both fields have a `RequiredFieldValidator` and another validator. In the case of the **From**, the other validator is a `RegularExpressionValidator`. Since the **To** has an email address, its correct email address of *Invalid* is displayed and since it is not empty, *Required* is not displayed. My aim is to display the error at the rightmost corner, regardless of whether it is a `RequiredFieldValidator` or a `RegularExpressionValidator` and regardless of the relative structural position of the tag among its siblings. To keep things simple, I paste the structure I have for the **From**:

```
        <div class="ui-field">
            <label class="ui-label" for="<%= From.ClientID %>">From</label>
            <span class="ui-field-req">&nbsp;*</span>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="FromValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="From" CssClass="ui-field-error" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="FromEmailValidator" runat="server" CssClass="ui-field-error" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ControlToValidate="From" ErrorMessage="Invalid" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            <asp:TextBox ID="From" runat="server" CssClass="ui-input"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
```

This is the relevant part of CSS I have written for the page:

```
    .ui-form .ui-field-error {
        float: right;
    }
```

And this is what we have generated for the **From** as HTML:

```
<div class="ui-field">
                <label class="ui-label" for="ctl00_PageBody_From">From</label>
                <span class="ui-field-req">&nbsp;*</span>
                <span id="ctl00_PageBody_FromValidator" class="ui-field-error" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">Required</span>
                <span id="ctl00_PageBody_FromEmailValidator" class="ui-field-error" style="color: red; visibility: visible;">Invalid</span>
                <input name="ctl00$PageBody$From" type="text" value="rocli@cablevision.com" id="ctl00_PageBody_From" class="ui-input">
            </div>
```

Final detail: If I remove the inner text of *Required* of the `RequiredFieldValidator`, then Invalid will jump to the right place. Is there a way either in plain CSS or some properties/attributes in ASP.NET to resolve this? If not, then the solution will involve Javascript DOM watchers which I would like to avoid.

Comment: add `Display = Dynamic` on your `RequiredFieldValidator`

Comment: @techspider, thanks, I am testing it right now. Can you explain why should this solve the problem?

Comment: `Display` property controls the space on the page for the `ErrorMessage` of your validation control.  Since you didn't mention it, the default values adds space to the message length equivalent to it.  Adding `Dynamic` will only add space dynamically when it requires

Comment: @techspider, when you say "when it requires", do you mean the case when the error message is shown?

Comment: exactly, the space is added only when validation fails

Comment: @techspider, test is successful, thanks! If you convert the ideas described here into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be controlled by specifying `Display` property of your validator.  Since you do not want white space to occupy when there is no corresponding error message, you need to set your `Display` property to `Dynamic`.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="FromValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="From" 
    CssClass="ui-field-error" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic"/>
```

When you do not set this property, the default value of `Static` is considered and space is occupied by the control equivalent to the length of the message you have on `ErrorMessage` property of that control.

`Dynamic` ensures that space for error message on the page is utilized only when validation fails for that control.

This [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.display(v=vs.110).aspx) describes more about this property.

Comment: Very nice. My problem was that by not specifying this value I was using the default value as Static.